# shell Script NO lines are append from input file using time stamp

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ksh

INPUT-file is `/var/log/error.log`

```
 Apr 7 05:58:05 ip-172-31-19-169 kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map: critical     
 Apr 7 09:21:12 ip-172-31-19-169 kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map: critical     
 Apr 7 13:05:57 ip-172-31-19-169 kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map: critical
```

My Script

```
#!/bin/ksh

d1=$(date --date="-50 min" "+%b %_d %H:%M")

d2=$(date "+%b %_d %H:%M")

while read line; do

    [[ $line > $d1 && $line < $d2 || $line =~ $d2 ]] && echo $line | egrep -wi '[Cc]ritical' >> /mnt/dinesh/ksh-scripts/draft/text.txt

done < /var/log/error.log
```

While running my script the system TIME is around `13:06:05`

So as per the script the `/mnt/dinesh/ksh-scripts/draft/text.txt` FILE should have the last entry of my `error.log` But NO lines are appened in `mnt/dinesh/ksh-scripts/draft/text.txt`.

Can someone help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Proper question formating will help you get answers.  For code, you can use the {} icon in the editor.  Make sure to read the available help in the editor.  I did it for you, the first one is free :-)

Comment: What debug have you done?  Ex. in your line inside the while, did you try with just the `echo  $line`?  Remove the grep, you will see if you get any line.  Then add the grep, see if you do get `[Cc]ritical` lines, ...  This will allow you to debug your `[[ ]]` conditions.

Comment: @Nic3500. Thanks for making the changes to my question. Yup, I have removed the grep and just used the echo $line to get check the output. But still, the output is it's empty

Comment: I fixed the Issues. 
1. In the Input file. The current system date is not modified.

Answer (score 0):

The essential problem with the logic of the code is that is using string comparisons to compare dates. In a string comparison, `Apr 17` is less than `Apr 2` and `Feb 1` is less than `Jan 1`.

Instead, the pattern in POSIX shells, is to turn the date into seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, also known as the "epoch".

For the `date` command the way to give time in this seconds format to set `FORMAT` to  `+%s`, e.g. `date +%s`.

In `ksh` there is a `printf` format specifier, `T`, to turn a string such as a line read in from your log file into the number of second since the epoch. See https://www.unix.com/302701867-post4.html?s=860f6c21431fa69ef9e083161f93739d

Here is your script rewritten to address the logic bug by converting comparisons to seconds:

```
#!/bin/ksh
ERROR_LOG=/tmp/error.log
FILTERED_ERROR_LOG=/tmp/text

now_secs=$(date "+%s")
start_secs=$(date --date="-30000 min" +%s)

while read line; do
    # Below stderr is redirected since I can't figure out how to get just the first part
    # of the date parsed skipping the other stuff after that.
    # Even though there is warning printed, the time comes out parsed correctly
    line_secs=$(printf "%(%#)T" "$line" 2>/dev/null)

    if (( $line_secs > $start_secs && line_secs < now_secs || line_secs == now_secs )); then
        echo $line | egrep -wi '[Cc]ritical' >> $FILTERED_ERROR_LOG
    fi
done < $ERROR_LOG
```

Some additional notes.

It appears like you more broadly may want to understand such debug such problems. As you can see, asking on StackOverflow such a very specific kind of problem is probably not going to be of much interest to others so it may take a while to get any sort of meaningful response.

The basic trace option is `-x`.  Let's run that on the above script:

```
ksh -x /tmp/bug.ksh
+ ERROR_LOG=/tmp/error.log
+ FILTERED_ERROR_LOG=/tmp/text
+ date +%s
+ now_secs=1587473181
+ date '--date=-30000 min' +%s
+ start_secs=1585673181
+ 0< /tmp/error.log
+ read line
+ printf '%(%#)T' 'Apr 7 05:58:05 ip-172-31-19-169 kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map: critical'
+ 2> /dev/null
+ line_secs=1586253485
+ (( 1586253485 > 1585673181 && line_secs < now_secs || line_secs == now_secs ))
+ egrep -wi '[Cc]ritical'
+ echo Apr 7 05:58:05 ip-172-31-19-169 kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map: critical
+ 1>> /tmp/text
+ read line
+ printf '%(%#)T' 'Apr 7 09:21:12 ip-172-31-19-169 kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map: critical'
+ 2> /dev/null
+ line_secs=1586265672
+ (( 1586265672 > 1585673181 && line_secs < now_secs || line_secs == now_secs ))
+ egrep -wi '[Cc]ritical'
+ echo Apr 7 09:21:12 ip-172-31-19-169 kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map: critical
+ 1>> /tmp/text
+ read line
+ printf '%(%#)T' 'Apr 7 13:05:57 ip-172-31-19-169 kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map: critical'
+ 2> /dev/null
+ line_secs=1586279157
+ (( 1586279157 > 1585673181 && line_secs < now_secs || line_secs == now_secs ))
+ egrep -wi '[Cc]ritical'
+ echo Apr 7 13:05:57 ip-172-31-19-169 kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map: critical
+ 1>> /tmp/text
+ read line
```

I changed your code in a couple of ways so as to make it easier to debug and see the problem. Putting what you want to do, append to a log file, as a separate statement in an `if` rather than as part of an `&&` condition, in a trace like the above, you'll see that show up as a separate line. In particular when you see:

```
+ egrep -wi '[Cc]ritical'
+ echo Apr 7 05:58:05 ip-172-31-19-169 kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map: critical
```

we know that the test succeeded. If you were wondering whether the time test was failing because of the first part (time is not new enough) or the second part (time is too new) or doesn't match the third part (time is now), then putting these in their own `if` or `else` would allow a trace to show that.

However I've done something else to make this simpler to debug. Although 
with a construct like `(( $line_secs > $start_secs ))` ksh will warn with:

```
/tmp/bug.ksh: warning: line 14: variable expansion makes arithmetic evaluation less efficient
```

because it would prefer the more efficient `(( line_secs > start_secs ))` instead, by adding the extra substitution using `$` you'll see the values compared in a trace. And this may help you figure out which part is failing.

If you knew this already and tried that, then I think you'll get more responses if you come to StackOverflow with the trace as shown above, and then the question is narrowed a little bit into "why is this comparision failing?" and you may get more repsonses quicker.

Lastly, I'll mention that I've written debuggers for modern `ksh93` newer than 2014-12-24, `zsh`, and `bash`. However when I tried the above example on `kshdb`, it failed and I am not sure why.